# Form Labels in Sonata and Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I want an inline edit form in my Admin but not in table form but rather standard. However when i put the edit mode as inline, the form is displayed without the labels in an ugly format. What can i do? Here's my code in the Admin

```
->with('Countries Involved')
            ->add('countries_involved', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
            'type_options' => array('delete' => false)
        ), array(
            'edit' => 'inline',
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can provide your custom template for the collection rendering using [Symfony Form Theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes). [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/SWQsV00JEQA) shows how to use custom theme in Sonata.